# angulajs data on the page is not loading after route redirection

Tags: angularjs

when I am at the home page and click on the link in the navigation bar

```
<li class="nav-item" ng-show="currentUser">
    <a class="nav-link" ng-show="currentUser" 
              ng-href="#/pictures"">Pictures</a>
</li>
```

It goes to the page, I can see the data is downloaded but it is not shown in the UI when update `$scope.urlListUI`.

```
 urlListInRoomUnits=loadPicture(filePathInRoomUnitPicture);
 $scope.urlListUI=urlListInRoomUnits;
 $scope.$apply();
 console.log('update ui: '+urlListInRoomUnits);
```

however, if I refresh the page, it will work.

the UI code

```
 <div ng-repeat = "urlRecord in urlListUI">
    <p>{{urlRecord[1]}}</p>
    <img ngf-src="urlRecord[0]" class="img-thumbnail">
 </div>
```

the function: loadPicture(filePathInRoomUnitPicture)

```js
        function loadPicture(pictureTypeFolder){
          console.log('loadpicture is running, input parameter:'+pictureTypeFolder);
          var urlList=[];
          $scope.whereThePictureIs=pictureTypeFolder;
          //list image from firebase storage
          var storageRefDownloadByPictureType = storageRef.child('airconPicture').child(pictureTypeFolder);
          storageRefDownloadByPictureType.listAll()
          .then(function(result) {
                console.dir(result);
                result.items.forEach(function(imageRef) {
                  // And finally display them
                  imageRef.getDownloadURL()
                  .then(function(url){
                    // TODO: Display the image on the UI
                    urlList.push([url,imageRef.name]);
                    })
                    .catch(function(error) {
                      // Handle any errors
                      });
                    });// end of for each download

                })// end of list all promise
          .catch(function(error) {
            // Handle any errors
          });
          return urlList;
        };// end of load Pciture by type
```

thanks for helping or direct me to the right source.

Comment: does `loadPicture` relate to angularjs?

Comment: it is a function to download picture url from firebase

Answer (score 0):

So what I see, first, you try to resolve `storageRefDownloadByPictureType.listAll()`

After resolving (let's say 1 sec), you run in a loop on results and try to resolve a list of items:

```
result.items.forEach(function(imageRef) {
  imageRef.getDownloadURL().then(function(url){

})
```

You resolve all at once, let's say, another 1 sec.

Your method does not return promise but empty `urlList` because you populate it in the next 2 seconds.

So instead `urlListInRoomUnits=loadPicture(filePathInRoomUnitPicture);`

It should be something like (you can write `loadPicture` in some service, lets say `MyService`):

```
MyService.loadPicture(filePathInRoomUnitPicture).then(function (urls) {

  //here you get all your results
  $scope.urlListUI = //...  
});
```

and now `loadPicture` `in MyService`:

```
this.loadPicture = function(filePathInRoomUnitPicture){

  //... 

  return storageRefDownloadByPictureType.listAll().then(function(result) {
     // create list of promises:

     var promises = [];

     result.items.forEach(function(imageRef) {                  
         promises.push(imageRef.getDownloadURL());
      })

      // chain promises
      return $q.all(promises);
    };
```

Comment: thank you so much Max, i will try this method, need to learn about services and promise first :). btw, does the same loading logic apply when i refresh the same page? when i refresh, it is working and the pictures are shown.

Comment: i tried the service with promise, it is still not working, i suspect the issue is becausee redirection with routeprovider wont load the page, but from the log i can see the data is loaded into the variable, but it just wont reflect on the UI.

Comment: What if you wrap the variable with `$timeout(function(){})` to trigger digest cycle